Type Compatibility issues
I am learning Typescript with React and i am having type compatibility issues while converting date.
Here is my data.ts file:
import { Result } from "./columns";

export enum Quality {
  High = "high",
  Medium = "medium",
  Low = "low",
}

// // The numbering represents the order the events are expected to occur,
// // First is the baseline, then the follow-up, and finally the conclusion.
// // All event's may not be present, but when they are, the earlier event will always be present.
export enum Event {
  Baseline = "Baseline",
  FollowUp = "FollowUp",
  Conclusion = "Conclusion",
}

// please do not edit the data, unless to add further examples
export const data: Result[] = [
  {
    patientId: "87gd2",
    scannedAt: new Date("2021-08-03T12:00:00Z"),
    score: 0.81,
    event: Event.FollowUp,
    sampleQuality: Quality.Low,
    dateOfBirth: "1990-01-01",
  },
  {
    patientId: "87gd2",
    scannedAt: new Date("2021-08-01T12:00:00Z"),
    score: 0.92,
    event: Event.Baseline,
    sampleQuality: Quality.High,
    dateOfBirth: "1990-01-01",
  },
  {
    patientId: "87gd2",
    scannedAt: new Date("2021-08-08T12:00:00Z"),
    score: 0.43,
    event: Event.Conclusion,
    sampleQuality: Quality.Low,
    dateOfBirth: "1990-01-01",
  },
  {
    patientId: "js27h",
    scannedAt: new Date("2021-08-02T12:00:00Z"),
    score: 0.74,
    event: Event.Baseline,
    sampleQuality: Quality.Medium,
    dateOfBirth: "1993-02-12",
  },
  {
    patientId: "9782e",
    scannedAt: new Date("2021-08-03T12:00:00Z"),
    score: 0.25,
    event: Event.Baseline,
    sampleQuality: Quality.Medium,
    dateOfBirth: "1981-04-12",
  },
  {
    patientId: "9782e",
    scannedAt: new Date("2021-08-21T12:00:00Z"),
    score: 0.21,
    event: Event.FollowUp,
    sampleQuality: Quality.High,
    dateOfBirth: "1981-04-12",
  },
];

And here are my interfaces
export interface Result {
  patientId: string; // the client specific identifier
  scannedAt: Date; // the time at which the sample was digitally scanned
  score: number; // the score of the sample
  event: Event; // the event that the sample was taken at
  sampleQuality: Quality; // the quality of the sample
  dateOfBirth: string; // the date of birth of the patient
}

export interface FormattedResult extends Result {
  formattedScannedAt: string;
  formattedDateOfBirth: string;
}


And here is my data formatter function:
export const formattedData: FormattedResult[] = data.map((item) => ({
  ...item,
  sampleQuality: formatQuality(item.sampleQuality),
  scannedAt: item.scannedAt.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "long",
    day: "numeric",
  }),
  score: item.score.toFixed(2),
  dateOfBirth: new Date(item.dateOfBirth).toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "long",
    day: "numeric",
  }),
}));


In this formatter function it is giving the error like :

Type '{ sampleQuality: QualityValue; scannedAt: string; score: string; dateOfBirth: string; patientId: string; event: Event; }[]' is not assignable to type 'FormattedResult[]'.
Type '{ sampleQuality: QualityValue; scannedAt: string; score: string; dateOfBirth: string; patientId: string; event: Event; }' is missing the following properties from type 'FormattedResult': formattedScannedAt, formattedDateOfBirth

I want to know what is wrong i am doing here.

You've defined formattedData as FormattedResult[] therefore it must include properties named formattedScannedAt and formattedDateOfBirth and you haven't added them to the returned object.

It looks like you're overwriting the original scannedAt and dateOfBirth properties instead of using your new formattedScannedAt and formattedDateOfBirth ones. Maybe you intended to do the following instead?
export const formattedData: FormattedResult[] = data.map((item) => ({
  ...item,
  sampleQuality: formatQuality(item.sampleQuality), // Do you also want a formattedSampleQuality?
  formattedScannedAt: item.scannedAt.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "long",
    day: "numeric",
  }),
  score: item.score.toFixed(2), // Do you also want a formattedScore?
  formattedDateOfBirth: new Date(item.dateOfBirth).toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "long",
    day: "numeric",
  }),
}));


But the date didn't convert back. I want the date like August 1, 2021 but it is giving me the date like this 2021-08-03T12:00:00Z after i added formattedScannedAt. scannedAt is a Date type and dateOfBirth is a string. No need to dateOfBirth

@AwaisRaza Your question isn't asking about the formatting, you're asking about type compatibility errors, which this answer fixes for you. If you are also having runtime issues you should ask about those separately.  Note that you've got item.score.toFixed(2) where a number is wanted so this is also incorrect.
